# Cómo hacer spinner enlazado en Swift Xcode

Tags: android, ios, swift, xcode

Acabo de terminar una app en Android y ahora estoy desarrollándola para IOS, pero tengo un problema. No sé cómo enlazar dos selectores, uno de países y otro de ciudades. Es decir, necesito poner dos pickerview que cambien dependiendo de lo que seleccione en una de ellas. Por ejemplo, si escojo el país X en el pickerview1 deberían salirme las ciudades del país X en el pickerview2.

De qué manera se puede hacer esto? Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El método `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent)` te puede ayudar a saber cuándo el usuario ha cambiado el valor del *pickerView1*, y posteriormente `reloadComponent(_)` (o `reloadAllComponents()`) para el *pickerView2*.

---

## Ejemplo

En el siguiente ejemplo hay dos `UIPickerView`: el primero (*pickerView1*) de dos componentes para encapsular ahí mismo tanto los países como las ciudades (por si sirve de ayuda), y el segundo (*pickerView2*) que sólo desplega las ciudades de acuerdo al país seleccionado en el primer componente del *pickerView1*:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Data Source

    var countries = [
        "Argentina",
        "Brasil",
        "Chile",
        "Perú"
    ]

    var cities = [
        "Argentina" : ["Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "Mendoza", "Rosario"],
        "Brasil"    : ["Brasilia", "Rio de Janeiro", "Salvador", "São Paulo"],
        "Chile"     : ["Arica", "Concepción", "Santiago", "Viña del Mar"],
        "Perú"      : ["Arequipa", "Cusco", "Lima", "Trujillo"]
    ]

    // Subviews

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView1: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView2: UIPickerView!


    //MARK: - Life cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        pickerView1.dataSource = self
        pickerView1.delegate = self
    
        pickerView2.dataSource = self
        pickerView2.delegate = self
    }

}


//MARK: - Picker View Data Source

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        if pickerView == pickerView1 {
            return 2 //Dos componentes: uno para el país y otro para la ciudad
        } else if pickerView == pickerView2 {
            return 1 //Sólo un componente para desplegar la ciudad del país
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView == pickerView1 {
            if component == 0 { // El componente de los países
                return countries.count
            } else { // El componente de las ciudades
                return cities.count
            }
        } else if pickerView == pickerView2 {
            return cities.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

}


//MARK: - Picker View Delegate

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate {

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == pickerView1 {
            if component == 0 {
                return countries[row] // Regresamos el valor correspondiente de los países (componente 0) para la fila correspondiente
            } else {
                let countryRow = countries[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] //Obtenemos primero cuál fila está seleccionada en el componente de los países
                return cities[countryRow]?[row] // Regresamos el valor de la fila correspondiente para el país seleccionado en el componente 0
            }
        } else if pickerView == pickerView2 {
            let countryRow = countries[pickerView1.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] // Obtenemos cuál es el país seleccionado (componente 0) del _pickerView1_
            return cities[countryRow]?[row] // Regresamos el valor de la fila correspondiente para el país seleccionado en el componente 0 del _pickerView1_
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView == pickerView1 && component == 0 { // Sólo actualizaremos los pickerViews cuando el usuario modifique el país (componente 0) del _pickerView1_
            pickerView1.reloadComponent(1) //Actualizamos las ciudades (componente 1) del _pickerView1_
            pickerView2.reloadComponent(0) //Actualizamos el único componente del _pickerView2_... también podría llamarse la función `pickerView2.reloadAllComponents()`
        }
    }

}
```

**PS:** Por "simplicidad", decidí que tando el `dataSource` y el `delegate` fueran el mismo para ambos `UIpickerView` y no tener que crear más clases. Pero creo está claramente explicado en el código la lógica de cada uno de los métodos de ambos protocolos.